# Predicate control in Prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate

Have a curiosity related to Prolog predicate control.

Supposedly I have a predicate f(A,X) and g(B).

```
f(A,X):- a,b,c, g(X).
g(B):- true.

a - returns true
b - returns true.
c - returns false.
where a,b and c are random predicates.
```

How can I continue to evaluate `g(X)` in the predicate `f(A,X)` if c returns false?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your intention is to define `f(A,X)` such that `g(X)` should be evaluated whether or not `c` fails, then either:

1. You could encode this using implication (`->`) and/or disjunction (`;`), ***or***
2. `f(A,X)` *doesn't need to be defined in terms of* `c`. This assumes `c` has no *side-effects* (e.g., asserting database facts using `assert`, or printing IO to a stream) which alter the environment and which cannot be undone on failure of `c`, in which case the first option is preferable.

There are several alternatives for using disjunction, such as:

```
f(A,X) :- ((a, b, c) ; (a, b)), g(X).
```

This definition (above) doesn't depend on `c` at all, but it will always execute `c` (as long as `a` and `b` succeed). The disjunction (`;`) allows PROLOG to backtrack to try executing `a, b` *again* if `c` failed at all, and to continue onto `g(X)`. Note that this is equivalent to:

```
f(A,X) :- a, b, c, g(X).
f(A,X) :- a, b, g(X).
```

In order for PROLOG not to backtrack to evaluate `f(A,X)` twice because of the second (identical) head predicate `f(A,X)` for every evaluation, you may choose to place a cut (`!`), if your implementation supports it, *immediately after* the `c` subgoal in the first clause. The cut is placed *after* `c` because we don't want the interpreter to commit to that choice of `f(A,X)` clause if `c` had failed, instead, we want the interpreter to fail out of this clause and to try the next one, to effectively ignore `c` and to continue processing `g(X)`.

Also note that this solution relies on `a` and `b` having no side-effects, because when `c` fails, `a` and `b` are executed again. If all `a`, `b`, and `c` have side effects, you can try using *implication*:

```
f(A,X) :- a, b, (c -> g(X) ; g(X)).
```

This will also effectively always execute `g(X)` whether `c` fails or not, and will not execute `a` and `b` again if `c` fails. This single-clause definition will also not leave a  choice-point like the previous suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could wrap `c` in `ignore/1`. Consider e.g.

```
?- false, writeln('Hello World!').
false.

?- ignore(false), writeln('Hello World!').
Hello World!
true.
```

But why would you want to continue if `c` fails? What's the use case?

I tested this code in SWI-Prolog, I'm not sure if other Prologs have `false/0` and `ignore/1`.
The latter can be defined like this though:

```
ignore(Goal) :- Goal, !.
ignore(_).
```

Comment: +1 for asking why this would be useful. The portable failure predicate is `fail`, btw. (Which is trivial to implement: `fail :- 0=1.`)

Comment: One scenario where you might want to continue if `c` fails is when `c` has _side-effects_; see my answer to this question for more detail.