# Prolog "or" operator, query

Tags: syntax, prolog, operators, logic

I'm working on some prolog that I'm new to.

I'm looking for an "or" operator

```
registered(X, Y), Y=ct101, Y=ct102, Y=ct103.
```

Here's my query. What I want to write is code that will:

"return X, given that Y is equal to value Z OR value Q OR value P"

I'm asking it to return X if Y is equal to all 3 though. What's the or operator here? Is there one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can 'invoke' alternative bindings on `Y` this way:

```
...registered(X, Y), (Y=ct101; Y=ct102; Y=ct103).
```

Note the parenthesis are required to keep the correct execution control flow. The `;`/2 it's the general `or` operator. For your restricted use you could as well choice the more idiomatic

```
...registered(X, Y), member(Y, [ct101,ct102,ct103]).
```

that on backtracking binds Y to *each* member of the list.

**edit** I understood with a delay your last requirement. If you want that Y match *all* 3 values the or is inappropriate, use instead

```
...registered(X, ct101), registered(X, ct102), registered(X, ct103).
```

or the more compact

```
...findall(Y, registered(X, Y), L), sort(L, [ct101,ct102,ct103]).
```

findall/3 build the list in the very same order that registered/2 succeeds. Then I use sort to ensure the matching.

```
...setof(Y, registered(X, Y), [ct101,ct102,ct103]).
```

setof/3 also sorts the result list

Comment: Thanks, this helped a ton. I wasn't sure how to go about it, but I'm going to read up on bindings and backtracking. Appreciated!

Answer (score 43):

Just another viewpoint.  Performing an "or" in Prolog can also be done with the "disjunct" operator or semi-colon:

```
registered(X, Y) :-
    X = ct101; X = ct102; X = ct103.
```

For a fuller explanation:

[Predicate control in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115021/predicate-control-in-prolog)